# Ways to go around assigning an item to a string?

Tags: python, string, python-2.x

I am trying to rewrite a formula by counting how many parenthesis are there in a formula.Starting with **s=0** and increase **s** whenever finding a "(" and decrease it when finding a ")" but leaving "(" and ")" corresponding to their original indices in the new string. This sounds very simple, and probably it should be so, but I am failing to find the solution . This is what I coded:

```
def parenthesis(text):
s=0
result=""


for character in text :

    if character=="(":   
        s+= 1
    if s>0 :
        result+= str(s)
    if s==0 :
        result+=str(0)
    elif character==")":       
        s-=1
return result
```

For this input:

```
print parenthesis("(asss)+(aa(12))")
```

I get

```
111111011122221
```

And I am having problem in assigning "(" and ")" to the the numbers that correspond to the original indices.

like:

```
(1111)0(11(22))
```

I was trying for many times now to implement something similar to  this:

```
for i in range(len(result)):
    if result[i-1]<result[i]: 
        result[i] = "("
    if result[i-1]>result[i]:
        result[i] = ")"
```

But of course this is a string assignment and it won't work like this, so my question is how can I go around this or if there is a simpler way am all ears, grateful for any help.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do here? See if the parentheses are balanced? Your current algorithm would always return `0` in that case. It would, however, also return `0` for `)(`, which is clearly not balanced. If your problem is just how to count, don't try to count into a string, count using a normal integer and convert that to a string when needed as such.

Comment: when the character is either `)` or `(` don't you want to add that to `result` instead of `s`?

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen Yes, but problem with that I will have an extra  +1  value for the parenthesis, which I want to substitute it with.

Comment: @user2722968 I apologize if my question was not clear, I edited it . I am trying to rewrite the formula, and i thought by this counting method it will be easier.

Comment: @Fred let me repeat that: when the character is either ( or ) don’t you want to add that to the result __*instead of *__ s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the parentheses to the result after identifying them. You just add to the count.

Looks like you're looking for something like this:

```
def parenthesis(text):
   count = 0
   result = ""

   for character in text:
      if character == "(":   
         count += 1
         result += "("
      elif character == ")":
        count -= 1
        result += ")"
      else:
        result += str(count)

   return result

print parenthesis("(asss)+(aa(12))")
```

This outputs:

```
(1111)0(11(22))
```